# How do I evaluate the the nth root of Lebesgue measure of a ball

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I try to calculate :
$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty } \sqrt[n]{\lambda_n(B(0,1))}$$

I know that 
$$ \lambda_n(B(0,1))={\pi^{n/2}\over \Gamma\left({n\over2}+1\right)}\qquad(n\geq1)\ $$

And I tried to use Gamma function properties to transform this equation but I didn't managed to find any useful form.

Comment: Try applying Stirling's formula.

Comment: Can i use it even though that the argument of gamma funcion can be not natural ?

Comment: @Pablo: Stirling's formula is an asymptotic result about the behavior of $n!$, or equivalently $\Gamma(n+1)$ which is defined for all $n\gt -1$, and since you're dealing with limits with $n\to\infty$, you can surely use it here. Another approach might be via the Stolz-Caesaro theorem.

Comment: @Pablo Yes, Stirling works just as well for real (indeed even complex) arguments.